# Extend interface defined in .d.ts file not recognized on compile

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord, discord.js

So I was creating a Discord bot with the Discord.js library and Typescript, but I can't figure out why the class that I extended is working on the eslint, but not in the compiler.

This is where I create the client object.

```
const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    "GUILDS",
    "GUILD_MESSAGES",
    "GUILD_MEMBERS"
  ]
});
```

Which has the class Client, that don't have these properties:

```
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();

client.loadEvents = (botObject: typeof bot, reload: boolean) => require("./handlers/events")(botObject, reload);

client.loadEvents(bot, false);
```

So I created a **discord.d.ts** file at the root of the project on */types/common/discord.d.ts* extending the class from Discord.js

```
import { Collection } from "discord.js";
import bot from "../../src/index";

declare module "discord.js" {
  export interface Client {
    commands: Collection<unknown, any>;
    events: Collection<unknown, any>;
    loadEvents: (botObject: typeof bot, reload: boolean) => any;
  }
}
```

But it only works for the eslint, when I try to compile the bot it gives me the following error:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/index.ts:39:8 - error TS2339: Property 'commands' does not exist on type 'Client<boolean>'.

39 client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
          ~~~~~~~~
src/index.ts:40:8 - error TS2339: Property 'events' does not exist on type 'Client<boolean>'.

40 client.events = new Discord.Collection();
          ~~~~~~
src/index.ts:42:8 - error TS2339: Property 'loadEvents' does not exist on type 'Client<boolean>'.

42 client.loadEvents = (botObject: typeof bot, reload: boolean) => require("./handlers/events")(botObject, reload);
          ~~~~~~~~~~
src/index.ts:44:8 - error TS2339: Property 'loadEvents' does not exist on type 'Client<boolean>'.

44 client.loadEvents(bot, false);
```

Can anyone please tell me what I'm missing here.

Comment: Hard to tell from the fragments you show... Are you importing the discord.d.ts somewhere?  Hmm: did you consider actual: class Client extends Discord.Client ?

Comment: @JackPunt I did not import it anywhere, should I? And also, where should I put "class Client extends Discord.Client"?

Comment: Might help to see more, and what you mean by: "is working on the eslint, but not in the compiler"; presumably eslint is finding the discord.d.ts, because it "just knows to look for d.ts files?" If you had "import {discord} from '..pathTodiscord.d.ts'" then the compiler would know where to find the type info.  My default suggestion would be do create an actual class Client extends Discord.Client {...} adding field/method declarations; presumably in a file named "client.ts" in your project source. Then you have a 'real class', not just some Type defns... But extending by declare could also work.